# Input value and background formula in same cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building an Excel sheet where I would like to have a background formula in the same cell as an random number input.

Here is the values today.

```
A1: 100<Br>
A2: 200<BR>
A3: 300

C1: 1,1
```

I would like `A1`, `A2` and `A3` multiply with `C1` as you hit enter after you inputted the value. Than I would like to change the value in `C1` in future and all the values in `column A` would be updated accordingly.

If I make an input of 100 I would like it to update it to 110 in above example, but if I later change `C1` to `1,2` than it would automatically become 120.

This would of course be super easy to do in another column like in `B:` "`=A1*$C$1`". But I really would like to only use one cell for this document.

This is impossible to do without `VBA`? If yes, how do I do this I `VBA`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One cell can't have a formula and input, it's kind of a circular reference. Also a function cannot change a cell. I suppose you could have an `OnChange` event but it could get messy.  On Change checks if that cell was changed, if so turn off events, do your multiplication, and turn events back on.  I wouldn't recommend it though.  You know you can hide rows & columns right?

Comment: Okey, maybe this is'nt a good idea then. Yeah, hiding columns would not be an option in this case. Is it possible and a good idea to do it a little more manually than? Can I have a button beside C1 and if i press the button It takes the value in C1 and mulitply it with A1, A2, A3 etc? And if I change the value in C1 and the press the button again the A column will be updated again? That is possible and a better option?

Comment: yes you could but what if you only changed one cell in the range at some point? You don't want to multiply the whole lot by 1.1 then do you?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I would like to change the start value with a multiplier. I would also like to go back to change C1 to 1 sometimes to se A-columns input values. Any Ideas how this is solved best?

Comment: why is the simple helper column a no go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited after OP's clarifications**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim values As Variant
    Dim rngToChange As Range
    Dim targetRow As Long

    Select Case True
        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A3")) Is Nothing
            Set rngToChange = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A3"))
            If Target.Count = 1 Then targetRow = Target.Row

        Case Target.Address = "$C$1"
            Set rngToChange = Range("A1:A3")

        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    With Range("C1")
        If .Comment Is Nothing Then .AddComment(Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A3").Value), " ")).Visible = False
        values = Split(.Comment.Text, " ")
        If targetRow <> 0 Then
            values(targetRow - 1) = Target.Value
            .ClearComments
            .AddComment(Join(values, " ")).Visible = False
        End If
    End With

    Dim cell As Range
    On Error GoTo goodexit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cell In rngToChange
        cell.Value = values(cell.Row - 1) * Range("c1").Value
    Next

goodexit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This works almost exactly as I wanted, thank you for this! The only minor setback i have found its not possible to change the input value(start value) in column A without first changing the comments. Is it possible to add something to the VBA so it is possibly to overwrite the comment if the start value in column A is changed?

Comment: you should add more info about the setback: give the exact sequence of operations starting from the empty sheet status on that raises it

Comment: For example, if the value in A1 is 100 and C1 is 1,1 then 100 will be stored in the comments in C1. But if I later want to change 100 to say for example 50 in A1 and I cant do that if I not first change the comments in C1 from 100 to 50. If I change the cell in A1 to 50 than I would like it to directly multiply with the value in 1,1 so in this case it would be 55 after I hit enter. I would like to have the possibility to change the cell directly in A1 and that this new value will be stored in the comments in C1. And this I would like to be possible to do in A1, A2, A3 etc.

Comment: see edited code. if it solves your question you may consider marking it as accepted. thank you

Comment: Nice idea to store the joined start values in a cell comment +:)

Comment: @T.M., thanks. Let's see if Allegany likes that, too

Comment: @DisplayName This works exactly as I wanted. Thank you so much! To bad I cant upvote this because of no reputation. Thank you again!